# Where can I download the LEGO Mindstorms NXT 2.0 IDE?

Tags: nxt, software

I want to see how well that IDE runs on my old Windows XP laptop.

I looked on www.lego.com, but it seems to all be documentation (downloads).

Comment: Is [this](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/support/files/default.aspx#Advanced) what you were looking for?

Comment: I wouldn't mind finding it too, I'm stuck with 1.1 and I don't even have a clue where that CD actually is. And since my HDD crashed, I kinda need to reinstall it someday.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

LEGO has made it possible to [download a stand-alone installer for NXT-G 2.0](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/help/products/themes-sets/lego-education/lego-mindstorms-nxt-software-downloads-408100000007850). It's compatible with both Mac and Windows.

Alternatively, you can [download a disc image of the NXT-G 2.0 CD](http://service.lego.com/en-us/helptopics/products/themes/mindstorms/mindstorms-nxt/nxt-software-download).  The link contains instructions on how to use it (as it isn't as easy as downloading just an installer).

Comment: Thanks for proving me sooo wrong! Might be useful to safeguard this somewhere as LEGO isn't known for keeping old software available for long.

Comment: Joubarc, you are quite welcome.  I was pleased and surprised that LEGO made the software available like that, too.

Comment: For others, this answer also works/has instructions for mac.

Comment: Seems to be [here](http://service.lego.com/en-us/helptopics/products/themes/mindstorms/mindstorms-nxt/nxt-software-download) now

Comment: It might be a good idea to include those instructions as part of your answer - link-only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: Links are broken. This link has been valid for a long time: http://service.lego.com/en-us/HelpTopics/default.aspx?questionID=2655. Look for "How can I get a replacement for the LEGO® MINDSTORMS® NXT software for set 8547?"

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The Mindstorms NXT GUI, NXT-G, is distributed on a CD and is not available without the Mindstorms NXT kit. It's not explicitly stated, but you can think of the license included in the price (although what the actual licensing terms are I don't know). In any case LEGO does not offer it for download.</strike> (Edit: [I was so wrong](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/822/99) - I'll just leave the rest of this answer for the BrickLink reference).

If you want the actual CD, your best bet to acquire one is to get one from someone who doesn't need it. For example, someone who happened to buy two kits. There are some available on [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=4558560) as well.

You could also try to contact the LEGO customer service and see if you can get it straight from them (mention the item ID 4558460, it should help them find it) as well, but I suppose they'll just point you to the download.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

NXT-G 1.1 -> http://www.mediafire.com/download/ve0p528do3ap2qd/LEGO_MINDSTORMS_NXT_v1.1.iso

NXT-G 2.0 -> http://www.mediafire.com/download/00byev4ayhh2ius/LEGO_MINDSTORMS_NXT_v2.0.iso

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2017, the links in the older answers to this question all seem to be broken. However, there is still a download available for NXT 2.0 on the LEGO customer service website. This link seems to have withstood many years of changes to the LEGO website: http://service.lego.com/en-us/HelpTopics/default.aspx?questionID=2655.

Look for "How can I get a replacement for the LEGO® MINDSTORMS® NXT software for set 8547?" on that page.

There is also currently a page on the official Mindstorms site for the NXT software download. I'm not sure how long the link will last, but here it is: https://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/nxt-software-download.