# Why can't I install the NXT software on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: ev3, nxt, nxt-g

I just got an Mindstorms EV3 for Christmas, and learned that you can have the NXT communicate with the EV3 in the NXT software. I tried to install the NXT software on my Mac, but all that happens is a gray box pops up and stays there. I have macOS 10.13.2 High Sierra, and I'm wondering if that might be the problem because they don't update the NXT software anymore. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What software should I install for NXT on OSX El 10.11.2 Capitan?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7215/what-software-should-i-install-for-nxt-on-osx-el-10-11-2-capitan), as the exact MacOS version doesn’t really matter here.

Comment: I'm not aware of any feature like this. Perhaps you heard that the NXT can be programmed using the EV3 software?

Comment: NXT software can't know anything about the EV3. The EV3 software can program the NXT.